# MacBook Pro Connects to Wi-Fi but not the Internet

Tags: wifi, vpn

I am on a MacBook Pro 2012 running macOS 10.11.

Recently, I have been having a problem with my Wi-Fi. Specifically, whenever I disconnect from one Wi-Fi network and attempt to connect to another in a different location, I get no internet. The signal says I am fully connected to the new network, but I cannot access the internet.

Restarting the computer solves the problem, but it is a pain to restart the computer every time I want to connect to a different network as I travel with my computer a lot.

I recently installed VPN software and suspect this may be the root of the problem because I never had this problem before the VPN.

Can anyone give me some ideas to fix this?

Comment: Assuming you can ping different nodes on the network (i.e. the router), try restarting DNS.  Issue the command  `sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder`

Comment: Would uninstalling the VPN software be an option?

Comment: I'd really prefer not to.  I don't like the idea of my ISP collecting and sharing my browsing data.

Comment: sometimes it is enough if you just wait a minute or 2 before switching, the WiFi needs time to close all open ports, that is why it keeps telling you, you are still connected. Just try it and wait a while.

Answer (score 1):

Seamus is right, it seems an issue related to network and not your MacBook Pro, though, you could execute  network diagnostic Utility.

The Network Diagnostics utility will guide you through a series of questions and tests, based on  your ethernet or Wi-Fi connection to network configuration and DNS servers. Sometimes the utility is able to fix issues by itself , but,when it can’t, it usually provides lots of useful info regarding  the nature of the problem as well as to offer several suggestions in order to fix network issues.

regarding VPN, could you tell me if you use more IP at the same time ?

Answer (score -2):

This is a network issue, not a Mac issue. If you have two Access Points (APs) rather than two different WiFi networks, you *may* be able to do this, but the APs must be configured properly. If they're two different WiFi networks, I'd rate your chances somewhere between slim and none.